# $\det{\begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ C & D\end{bmatrix}}=(D-1)\det(A) +\det(A-BC) $?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, block-matrices

I found this identity in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices),

> When $D$ is a $1 \times 1$ matrix, $B$ is a column vector, and $C$ is a row vector, then
>
> $$\det{\begin{bmatrix} A &  B \\  C & D\end{bmatrix}}=(D-1)\det(A) +\det(A-BC)= (D+1)\det(A) -\det(A+BC)$$

I wonder how to prove that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

$$\mathrm M := \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm A & \mathrm c\\ \mathrm r^T & \alpha\end{bmatrix}$$

where $\mathrm A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ and $\mathrm c, \mathrm r \in \mathbb R^n$. Assuming that $\mathrm A$ is invertible,

$$\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} \mathrm I_n & 0_n\\ -\mathrm r^T \mathrm A^{-1} & 1\end{bmatrix}}_{\det (\cdot) = 1} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm A & \mathrm c\\ \mathrm r^T & \alpha\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm A & \mathrm c\\ 0_n^T & \alpha - \mathrm r^T \mathrm A^{-1} \mathrm c\end{bmatrix}$$

Hence,

$$\begin{array}{rl} \det (\mathrm M) &= \det \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm A & \mathrm c\\ 0_n^T & \alpha - \mathrm r^T \mathrm A^{-1} \mathrm c\end{bmatrix}\\\\ &= \det (\mathrm A) \cdot (\alpha - \mathrm r^T \mathrm A^{-1} \mathrm c)\\\\ &= (\alpha - 1) \cdot \det (\mathrm A) + \det (\mathrm A) \cdot (1 - \mathrm r^T \mathrm A^{-1} \mathrm c)\\\\ &= (\alpha - 1) \cdot \det (\mathrm A) + \det (\mathrm A) \cdot \det(\mathrm I_n - \mathrm A^{-1} \mathrm c \mathrm r^T)\\\\ &= (\alpha - 1) \cdot \det (\mathrm A) + \det(\mathrm A - \mathrm c \mathrm r^T)\end{array}$$

where we used [Weinstein-Aronszajn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein%E2%80%93Aronszajn_identity) to conclude that $1 - \mathrm r^T \mathrm A^{-1} \mathrm c = \det(\mathrm I_n - \mathrm A^{-1} \mathrm c \mathrm r^T)$.

Comment: Your answer is more rigorous! $+1$

Answer (score 4):

Observe that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B\\
C & D
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
A & B + 0\\
C & (D-1) + 1
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation*}

Therefore, using [multilinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Definition) of determinants
\begin{equation*}
\det\begin{bmatrix}
A & B\\
C & D
\end{bmatrix}
= \det \begin{bmatrix}
A & 0\\
C & D - 1
\end{bmatrix} + 
\det \begin{bmatrix}
A & B\\
C & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation*}

Now, the first determinant on the RHS [is equal to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices) $\det(A) \det(D  -1) = (D - 1) \det(A)$, and the second determinant is $\det([1])\det(A - B[1]^{-1}C) = \det(A - BC)$, from which the first form of the result follows. The second form is obtained similarly by writing $D = (D + 1) - 1$.